# Magento2 : How to remove details from shipment print shipping label

Tags: magento2, pdf, shipment

I want to remove description  from pdf file. it is generated from here. please check following path to print shipment file:

From admin menu : **Sales->Shipments->click any one shipments view link** now go to at shipping and payment method in that click on **"print shipping label"** button.

[image]

After clicked on it pdf file will be generated and in that file i want to remove **DESC** from file. please check following image.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found any solution how to change label pdf